# Working with api: Functions are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs, api, last.fm

I am new to react and trying to work with last fm api, but I got problem working with json page. When I try:

```
class App extends React.Component <{}, {items: Array<String>, DataisLoaded: boolean}> {
constructor(props: any) {
  super(props);
   
  this.state = {
    items: [],
    DataisLoaded: false
  };
}
   
componentDidMount() {
  fetch("https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettoptracks&api_key=6808816d086d4c48075217bd2cc178a1&format=json")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((json) => {
    this.setState({
      items: json,
      DataisLoaded: true
    });
  })
}

render() {
  const { DataisLoaded, items } = this.state;
  if (!DataisLoaded) return <div><h1>Pleses wait some time.... </h1></div>;
  
  return (
    <div className = "App">
      <h1> Fetch data from an api in react </h1>
      {Array.from(items).map((item: any) => ( 
        <ol>
          Name: { item.name }, 
        </ol>
        ))}
    </div>);
}
```

I got `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys).`

How to work with pages like that? How to map them? I tried several times, but don't understand. How to get name of the track and name of artist?

JSON page look like this:

```
{"tracks":{"track":[
{"name":"Bad Habit",
"duration":"0",
"playcount":"8259188",
"listeners":"539192",
"mbid":"",
"url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Steve+Lacy/_/Bad+Habit",
"streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},
"artist":{"name":"Steve Lacy","mbid":"ca9766a0-1c30-43e6-a213-bac1334efc4a","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Steve+Lacy"},
"image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/64s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/174s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/300x300/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png","size":"extralarge"}]}
}
],"@attr":{"page":"1","perPage":"50","totalPages":"626758","total":"31337870"}}}
```

Comment: If will help a lot to have the full code for this class component

Comment: Can you also add the content of the `json` response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here you're mapping through tracks and @attr which are objects.
what you want to do is reach the track inside tracks and map that

```
items.tracks.track.map
```

so what you should do is the following
after you fetch do

```
 this.setState({
    items: json.tracks.track,
    DataisLoaded: true
  });
```

and then

```
{items.map((item: any) => ( 
    <ol>
      Name: { item.name }, 
    </ol>
    ))}
```